# Ignore arrow key input on rich:scrollableDataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:scrollableDataTable on my JSF page. If I click a row, then hit the down arrow key to scroll the page, it instead changes the selection in the table. I don't want this to happen, for a number of reasons. Is there some way I can turn that off, or just eat that keypress outright?

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace the rich:scrollableDataTable with an rich:extendableDataTable you will be able to capture the onkeypress event.

```
<rich:rich:extendableDataTable ... onclick="Event.stop(event);" .../>
```

Or you can filter out only the up/down arrow keys with further js.